# Safari doesn't scale background?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im having a problem in Safari, that it doensn't scale the background - It works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome and so on, just safari that's the problem...
You can see it here: http://wearewebstars.dk/frontend/test/theme-front.html

It happens when you have a resolution that is under 1280px - Any ideas to that's wrong?

[image]

The background is set like this:

```
body#front-themepage {  background: transparent url(assets/css/img/themes/bg-front.jpg) top center no-repeat; width:100%;  }
```

I've also tried background-size:cover - And background-size: 100%, 100%, but it doenst work :(

Comment: Detect their resolution through javascript and swap in a larger image...

Comment: Cant do that, because the Image comes from a CMS, so I dont have any control of which image is used :/

Comment: Don't know, but if it's any help, my website at http://mattgibsonphoto.com is using `background-size: cover` and seems to scale just fine in Safari...

Answer (score 1):

Safari, and Chrome in some cases, require -webkit- to be specified for CSS selectors. This is for no reason other than Apple's design, and is (probably) no fault of your own. In all likelihood, this is the issue, but it may also be caused by something you have not displayed.